# my phpmyadmin showing blank screen

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, wampserver

My `localhost/phpmyadmin` displaying the blank screen.
My php Version is 5.3.0. I am using `Wamp` server.
Yesterday it was opened properly but today it's displaying the blank screen.
So whether is the problem in my code or in `wamp` server?

Comment: Check the `phpmyadmin` directory on your machine.

Comment: Check if all services are started.. mysql, apache etc

Comment: also i reinstalled my wamp server even it display like a blank screen

Comment: @RamyaaAjay is your localhost working properly?? i mean to say without phpmyadmin rest things working fine or not??

Comment: Try to open http://127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin

Comment: Can you tell us what you see when you open http://127.0.0.1 or http://localhost?

Comment: my localhost is working but localhost/phpmyadmin only not working

Comment: http://127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin is not opening

Comment: In my case, Windows 7 with WAMP, i used to set memory_limit = 8192M, and everything stop working - i was getting only blank screen everywhere. Not only in PHPMyAdmin.
Setting it back to memory_limit = 3072M it started work. With 4096M it's again not working!

Comment: jQuery might not be loading, it will be fine if you try later

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Skype then close/quit the Skype program and try restart the WAMP services again.

**UPDATE:**

Skype listens on port 80. It could be the reason for displaying a blank screen.

You can disable this option in Skype. Go to Skype menu, Tools -> Options -> Advanced ->  Connection -> Uncheck "Use port 80..."

Comment: port no. 80 is reserved by apachae, not mysql

Comment: @Prakash phpMyAdmin requires Apache, so I guessed Apache might not started due to Skype.

Comment: but, localhost/ is working... just the phpmyadmin isn't working.. 
am I right @RamyaaAjay? Please confirm this to more forward

Comment: yes my localhost is working only localhost/phpmyadmin is not working

Answer (score 0):

Possible reason I see for this are:

1. Your XAMPP / WAMP's `MYSQL` Service might not be started, recheck
2. Your `phpmyadmin` directory might be missing, reinstall service XAMPP/WAMP

http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,70332

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-server-73/http-localhost-phpmyadmin-shows-blank-page-937397/

http://www.oscmax.com/forums/oscmax-v2-installation-issues/22838-fresh-install-blank-localhost-phpmyadmin.html

these might help you

Comment: i reinstalled my wamp server but it display blank screen only

Comment: plz send any other details,I need to open my phpmyadmin

Comment: Enable `error_reporting` and short open tags and see if there is any change

Comment: i enabled error_reporting even my localhost/phpmyadmin is display blank screen

Answer (score 0):

may be chance for port occupied by some other services, im not sure, but try
start->run-> services.msc
stop the IIS services  if opened..

or

If you had skype means change the port of skype because skype and wamp are some port 80..

Thank you

Comment: I stopped iis service,also i m not using skype,even it display the blank screen

Comment: In cmd give
 netstat -an
find which is working in port 80 and stop that serivce

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6872576/how-to-open-port-80-for-apache-previously-occupied-by-visual-studios-servers verify with this,,,

Comment: after stop iis server,,, restart the wamp server,,,

Comment: apache only reserved port 80,i reinstalled and checked all the service even my phpmyadmin is display the blank screen

Comment: check also port 3306(mysql port)